# Create a numpy matrix from content in dictionary labelled by i,j

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

Suppose I have a dictionary:

```
d = {(0,0): 1, (0,1): 2, (1,0): 3, (1,1): 4}
```

I want to make this into the array (i.e. the keys correspond to array indices)

```
array([[1, 2],
       [3, 4]])
```

Is there a better way to do this than for loops?
(I tried `np.fromfunction` but it did not work.)

Comment: Where does the data come from in the first place?

Comment: @AMC this is an invented example, just to illustrate the principle.

Comment: Is it an example based on an actual problem you’re dealing with, or is it purely for the sake of curiosity/learning?

Comment: A general solution for this problem (which I have found in the meantime, I have added an answer) is very useful in many cases for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Coming back to answer my own question. The piece of the puzzle I was missing was np.vectorize(). Check this out:

```
d = {(0,0): 1, (0,1): 2, (1,0): 3, (1,1): 4}
f = lambda i,j: d[(i,j)]
g = np.vectorize(f)
arr = np.fromfunction(f, (2,2))
```

This gives me exactly what I wanted:

```
array([[1, 2],
       [3, 4]])
```

It was that simple.

Answer (score 2):

`items` gives a list of the keys and values, which you can easily use to assign values to a preallocated array.

```
In [624]: d = {(0,0): 1, (0,1): 2, (1,0): 3, (1,1): 4}                                         
In [625]: list(d.items())                                                                      
Out[625]: [((0, 0), 1), ((0, 1), 2), ((1, 0), 3), ((1, 1), 4)]
In [626]: res = np.zeros((2,2),int)                                                            
In [627]: for id,val in d.items(): 
     ...:     res[id]=val 
     ...:                                                                                      
In [628]: res                                                                                  
Out[628]: 
array([[1, 2],
       [3, 4]])
```

Alternatively assign elements with the `keys` and `values` list:

```
In [640]: k,v = list(d.keys()), list(d.values())                                               
In [641]: res[tuple(np.transpose(k))]=v                                                        
In [642]: res                                                                                  
Out[642]: 
array([[1, 2],
       [3, 4]])

In [643]: np.transpose(k)                                                                      
Out[643]: 
array([[0, 0, 1, 1],
       [0, 1, 0, 1]])
```

Answer (score 1):

It seems you have a dictionary of keys situation, which can be handled by `scipy`'s [`dok_matrix`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.14.0/reference/generated/scipy.sparse.dok_matrix.html):

```
from scipy.sparse import dok_matrix

d = {(0,0): 1, (0,1): 2, (1,0): 3, (1,1): 4}

mat = dok_matrix((2,2))
mat._update(d)
mat = mat.todense()
```

Which gives you:

```
>>> mat
matrix([[1., 2.],
        [3., 4.]])
```